# Get data from Facebook Event Page

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to programmatically retrieve data from a Facebook Event. For example, by using a url like so: https://www.facebook.com/events/
I would like to get data like: title, description, start time, and location. Tried scraping the page using Axios and cheerio, but it doesn't seem possible since some of the data loaded in is dynamic. Also not sure if this is against Facebook's terms and conditions. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This api endpoint used to be available with previous Graph API versions.

Unfortunately, Facebook has officially ended it and turned it off as of mid-Sept 2023. Facebook pages were being systematically converted to "New Pages". After that was complete, the "events" API was disabled.

The only way that you can do this now is by using the feed API endpoint, getting a listing of all posts, and then filtering it by events.

I had to redevelop a plugin for a charity website I manage and this worked for me. All API calls must use a access token, which you can generate on the Graph API Explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

There you can explore the Page data and set permissions on accessing the data.